# How do I compare the first and second items of a list in python?

Tags: python

So I am trying to compare the first item in a list to the second. I want to find out if the first item is equal to, less than, or greater than the second item.[Here is what I have so far. I'm stuck at this part :/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Hub.png)

```
numbers = []

for i in range(0,3):
  num = input("Please enter an integer: ")
  numbers.append(num)
```

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I do not know how to do either

Comment: I don't understand how you could have learned about "for" without learning about "if".  `if numbers[0] < numbers[1]:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have this code that will ask the user for 3 integers, and then you are adding them to the list numbers. You need first to convert then to integers by adding int(input(..))

```
numbers = []
for i in range(0,3): 
    num = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
    numbers.append(num)
```

Now we can start comparing the first and the second number of the list:

```
if numbers[0] > numbers[1]:
    print("the first number is bigger than the second")
elif numbers[1] > numbers[0]:
    print("the second number is bigger than the first")
else:
    print("the first and the second numbers are equal")
```